# Does anyone know how to uninstall freetds from MAC (osx-10.9.4) if installed from source?

Tags: macos, uninstallation, freetds

Does anyone know how to uninstall freetds from MAC?
I have installed it from source by following instructions:

tar zxvf freetds-stable.tgz

cd freetds-'0.91'

./configure --prefix=/usr/local

make

sudo make install

gem install tiny_tds -- --with-freetds-include=/usr/local/include --with-freetds-lib=/usr/local/lib --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/include --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/lib

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully uninstall freetds and tiny_tds gem.

first I uninstalled tiny_tds gem as below:

```
 gem uninstall tiny_tds
```

To uninstall freetds follow the instructions to configure and build the freetds before running make uninstall.(otherwise it will give this error: make: *** No rule to make target `uninstall'.  Stop.
)

```
cd freetds-'0.91'  
./configure --prefix=/usr/local   
make
sudo make uninstall
sudo make clean
```

You will have to remove freetds.conf file manually as below:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/etc/freetds.conf
```

To ensure you have successfully uninstalled freetds run the following:

```
tsql -C
```

It should not report freetds details.

Answer (score 0):

From the directory you ran 'sudo make install':

```
sudo make uninstall
sudo rm /usr/local/etc/freetds.conf
```

That should do it, but you'll have to uninstall the gem separately. Good luck.

Comment: the output of sudo make uninstall was : make: *** No rule to make target `uninstall'.  Stop. and I removed freetds.conf file from /usr/local/etc/freetds.conf